# Can Auth0 register an user to Firebase after an user registered his account through Auth0?

Tags: authentication, firebase, auth0

I am currently working on a project that use Auth0 as the Authentication and use Firebase to do a simple realtime chat.

Since I want to set some rules for security, registering users to Firebase is needed.

I found that Auth0 can integrate with Firebase. However, is it possible to register an user to Firebase after an user registered his account through Auth0 automatically?

Comment: See https://dzone.com/articles/firebase-authentication-with-the-firebase-30-sdk-a

Comment: Thanks but as the link mentioned: https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types, `As of 8 June 2017, new Auth0 customers cannot add any of the legacy grant types to their Clients. Only customers as of 8 June 2017 can add legacy grant types to their existing Clients.`. I just created my Auth0 account last week. So, I cannot use the delegation end point to exchange Firebase token...